# Reverse order words in a dynamic sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several tags like this:

```
<a class="classCover" href="#">1 Comment</a>
```

I would like to do this reversing the order of the words:

```
Comments (1)
```

My function is this but is not working:

```
$('.classCover').each(function(){
    $(this).text().split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
});
```

Please, any idea?

Comment: How are you rendering that link? Is it not a better idea to do it there? Yoiu also need to assign the changed text to the element: `$(this).text($(this).text().split(' ').reverse().join(''));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, except you're not doing anything with the result

```
$('.classCover').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().split(' ').reverse().join(' '));
});
```

Comment: I know what you mean, thank you so much. Anyway, what's the best way to get the number in brackets taking into account will change depending on the number of comments?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('.classCover').each(function(){

    var link = $(this).text().split(' ');
    $(this).text(link[1] + "(" + link[0] + ")");
});
```